# Path not changing (os.chdir)

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the last part #print(new_path), the output is "None". Can one explain me in detail the reason for the occurrence of this error. Thank you in Advance.

```
import os
def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\NISARG\Desktop\WinPython\prank")
    #print(file_list)

    saved_path= os.getcwd()
    print(saved_path)

    new_path= os.chdir(r"C:\Users\NISARG\Desktop\WinPython\prank")
    print(new_path)
```

Comment: It's because you are creating already exist path.

Comment: @vipulprajapati: no, that's not it. No directories are being created.

Answer (score 6):

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\NISARG\Desktop\WinPython\prank")    
new_path = os.getcwd()
print(new_path)
```

`os.chdir` operates by side-effect and always returns `None`. If you want the current working dir after a `chdir` you must ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `os.chdir()` does not return any value. Below is the fix.

```
import os

def rename_files():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\GenWork\Python3")
    #print(file_list)

    saved_path= os.getcwd()
    print(saved_path) # H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\GenWork\Python3

    os.chdir(r"H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects")
    new_path = os.getcwd()
    print(new_path)   # H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects

rename_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) returns `None` in all cases.

If you want to know which directory your program is currently in, you must call [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

Additionally, if you want to make sure your program switches back to the original working directory safely, you could use a [contextlib.contextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

path = "/home"

# Save original working directory, assuming its / here
owd = os.getcwd()

@contextmanager
def change_working_directory(directory):
    try:
        os.chdir(directory)
        yield directory
    except FileNotFoundError:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(owd)

print("Before context manager: %s" % owd)
with change_working_directory(path) as directory:
    print("Inside context manager: %s" % directory)

print("After context manager: %s" % owd)
```

Which will show the following behaviour:

```
Before context manager: /
Inside context manager: /home
After context manager: /
```

**Explanation of context manager:**

Which switches to the directory in the `try` block, does something with the changed directory(in this case just print it), then switch back to the current working directory in the `finally` block when the context manager exits. The [FileNotFoundError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError) exception is also raised in the `except` block if the directory doesn't exist, and yields `None` from the generator.